# mybatis avoid inserting the same data

Tags: java, mybatis

new to mybatis

```
insert into table(name, age) values (name_value, age_value)
```

one record's name and value are same as another

how to use mybatis  to avoid it?

I am using xml to create mapper

Comment: what is your dbms?

Comment: Read about unique key (https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/unique.php), it is not DB specific at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not clear but, you have to define in your db a unique key. So, if you specify that name and age columns are unique, your dbms blocks all inserts of new rows that have name and age that already exists.

This is an example of mybatis query:

```
INSERT INTO mytable
        (name, age)
    VALUES
        (
        #{name},
        #{age}
        )
    ON CONFLICT (name,age)
    DO NOTHING
```

So it tries to insert a value into your table. If the dbms returns an error, becaus of the existence of a unique key (that is composed by [name and age]), it executes another operation. Instead of DO NOTHING, you can put after DO an UPDATE statement for example.